# Return All Duplicate Rows With Matching Elements in Another Column

Tags: sql, join, subquery

This is the original base table.

[image: Original Table]

I am looking to return all rows that have duplicate id values and have the same title for both of the duplicate id's.

So I am looking to return the rows

```
3 CEO
3 CEO
6 Janitor
6 Janitor
```

So far I have only been able to return the rows with duplicate id values using this code

```
select id, title 
from original_table
where id in
    (select id 
    from original_table
    group by id
    having count(id) > 1);
```

[image]

Any suggestions on how to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional condition:

```
select id, title 
from original_table
where id in
    (select id 
     from original_table
     group by id
     having count(id) > 1 and count(distinct title) = 1
    );
```

Comment: If it is the best solution to your problem. Then to mark an answer as accepted, click on the checkmark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to fill in. @Phil